# How to prevent PIL from distacting of a numpy array (image) when saving?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an array that is image

```
x = np.array([[[0, 100, 0],
               [100, 0, 0]],
              [[50, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 50]]])
```

I want to save it, load it, and I want to see the same array. I do

```
image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(x))
image.save('x.jpg')
temp = Image.open('x.jpg')
print(np.array(temp))
```

It results to

```
[[[116  22  10]
  [105  12   5]]

 [[ 39  10   4]
  [ 27   2   0]]]
```

As you see, the array is not the same, as the initial one. How do I prevent it?

Comment: Don't use a lossy format like JPEG. Use a lossless format like PNG instead.

Comment: thanks, now it's alright